# Convert file and copy LastWriteTime from source file

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell

I would like to convert videos and set time on them to be same as from source file.
I use batch for converting files in folder with ffmpeg

```
for %%a in ("*.MP4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "%%~naC.mp4"
pause
```

And then I have a powershell code which I use with excel to match files LastWriteTime

```
powershell (Get-ChildItem 'P1290526C.mp4').LastWriteTime = (Get-ChildItem 'P1290526.MP4').LastWriteTime
```

Is there any way how I can joint this two codes togather so I will use just one script/bat file?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does this have to do with excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the PowerShell command into the same for loop:

```
for %%A in ("*.MP4") do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%A" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "%%~nAC.mp4"
    powershell -NoP -C "(gi '%%~nAC.mp4').LastWriteTime = (gi '%%A').LastWriteTime"
)
```

`gi` is the alias for Get-Item, no need to iterate with Get-ChildItem.

As this will invoke powershell for every converted file it is more efficient to either:

- let powershell do the whole job
- or run powershell only once after converting all files